# Averaging when iterating over numpy array

Tags: python, loops, numpy, multidimensional-array, mean

I have a dataset called MEL of shape (94824,) wherein most instances have shape (99, 13) but some have smaller shapes. It consists of (float) MEL frequencies. I'm trying to put all the values in an empty numpy matrix of shape (94824, 99 , 13). So some instances are left empty. Any suggestions?

```
MEL type = numpy.ndarray
for i in MEL type(i) = <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
for j in i type (j) = <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Comment: I updated the answer. Please have a look and try the first half of the answer above the line separator

Comment: Thanks! It worked! I have a beautiful array of shape (85314, 99) now!

Comment: Cool, now you can train your network!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `MEL` array is not of homogeneous shape, first we need to filter out the arrays whose shape is common (i.e. `(99, 13)`). For this, we could use:

```
filtered = []
for arr in MEL:
    if arr.shape == (99, 13):
        filtered.append(arr)
    else:
        continue
```

Then we can initialize an array to hold the results. And then we can iterate over this filtered list of arrays and calculate the mean over axis 1 like:

```
averaged_arr = np.zeros((len(filtered), 99))

for idx, arr in enumerate(filtered):
    averaged_arr[idx] = np.mean(arr, axis=1)
```

This should compute the desired matrix.

---

Here is a demo to reproduce your setup, assuming all arrays of the same shape:

```
# inputs 

In [20]: MEL = np.empty(94824, dtype=np.object)

In [21]: for idx in range(94824):
    ...:     MEL[idx] = np.random.randn(99, 13)

# shape of the array of arrays
In [13]: MEL.shape
Out[13]: (94824,)

# shape of each array
In [15]: MEL[0].shape
Out[15]: (99, 13)
```

---

```
# to hold results
In [17]: averaged_arr = np.zeros((94824, 99))

# compute average
In [18]: for idx, arr in enumerate(MEL):
    ...:     averaged_arr[idx] = np.mean(arr, axis=1)

# check the shape of resultant array
In [19]: averaged_arr.shape
Out[19]: (94824, 99)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I'm getting the following error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-247-7a545beac940> in <module>()
----> 1 averaged_arr = np.zeros(94824, 99)

TypeError: data type not understood

Comment: MEL type = numpy.ndarray

Comment: Now it gives me this error: ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (87) into shape (99)

When I change the 99 in np.zeros to 87 it gives:
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (99) into shape (87)

Comment: I'm getting the value error stated above... 

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (87) into shape (99)

Apparently not all are shaped (99, 13) but some are shaped (87,13) I think.

Comment: So, this `ValueError` says somewhere in your `MEL` there is an array of shape `(87, 13)`. Aren't all arrays of the same shape? you can check the shapes of each array using a `for` loop and see if that's the case. If all arrays have the same shape, then this approach would definitely work.

Comment: You're right some have other shapes like for example (73, 13). Most are (99,13) though.

Comment: Then it's not possible to have an output array of shape `(94824, 99)`; This assumes that each array in your `MEL` is of shape  `(99, 13)`.

Comment: I want to format it as input for a neural network. Not sure how to get it in the right shape then.... Can you think of another way to shape it as a 2D matrix? (Not necessarily 94824, 99)

Comment: Is it okay if you can get rid of the arrays which are not of shape `(99, 13)`? I think then the dataset would be small, but that's the only approach that comes to my mind atm

Comment: I thought of that myself and I'm oke with that, however I need to keep the labels with the arrays so I have to add a column... Another possibility might be to make an empty 3D array with as dimensions; length(MEL), max length(first dimension MEL), max length(second dimension MEL), and fill it up with MEL? So that would be to make an array of shape (94824, 99, 13) and fill it up with the values in MELL?

Comment: I have edited the question, do you perhaps have a solution for that?

Comment: There are 85314 instances with shape (99, 13).